# MySQL Select and Join - Ambiguous column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join four tables together. The code works fine when I'm only comparing the EVENT_DATA and joining the PERSONA tables as I'm able to get the "Name" column from PERSONA (which doesn't exist in the EVENT_DATA table). However, one of the problems is that this "Name" column also exists in the CUSTOMCAR table, so I can only get one or the other. Additionally, when I tried adding the last join statement, the code wouldn't run at all.

If someone could please help me, that would be great!

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM EVENT_DATA
LEFT JOIN PERSONA ON EVENT_DATA.personaId = PERSONA.ID
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMCAR ON CUSTOMCAR.ownedCarId = EVENT_DATA.carId
LEFT JOIN CARCLASSES ON CARCLASSES.store_name = CUSTOMCAR.name
WHERE (EVENT_DATA.EVENTID = '299')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid `*` and use explicit columns list instead:

```
SELECT EVENT_DATA.personaId, ...
FROM EVENT_DATA
LEFT JOIN PERSONA ON EVENT_DATA.personaId = PERSONA.ID
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMCAR ON CUSTOMCAR.ownedCarId = EVENT_DATA.carId
LEFT JOIN CARCLASSES ON CARCLASSES.store_name = CUSTOMCAR.name
WHERE (EVENT_DATA.EVENTID = '299');
```

If you have same column name you need to to use aliasing:

```
SELECT ...
 CUSTOMCAR.NAME AS c_name,
 PERSONA.NAME AS p_name
...
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, so I've starting working on that code but I still am returned a duplicate value for "name" with the CUSTOMCAR and PERSONA table. Am I still doing something wrong here?


$sql = "SELECT EVENT_DATA.personaId, EVENT_DATA.alternateEventDurationInMilliseconds, EVENT_DATA.EVENTID, EVENT_DATA.rank, EVENT_DATA.carId, **PERSONA.name, CUSTOMCAR.name**
FROM EVENT_DATA
INNER JOIN PERSONA ON EVENT_DATA.personaId = PERSONA.ID
INNER JOIN CUSTOMCAR ON CUSTOMCAR.ownedCarId = EVENT_DATA.carId
WHERE (EVENT_DATA.EVENTID = '299')";

Comment: @County You have to rename column so you don't have duplicates: `PERSONA.name, CUSTOMCAR.name`. At least one should be aliased.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/):

```
$sql = "SELECT ed.*, 
               pa.*, 
               cc.*, 
               ccs.* 
        FROM EVENT_DATA AS ed
        LEFT JOIN PERSONA AS pa ON ed.personaId = pa.ID
        LEFT JOIN CUSTOMCAR AS cc ON cc.ownedCarId = e.carId
        LEFT JOIN CARCLASSES AS ccs ON ccs.store_name = cc.name
        WHERE (ed.EVENTID = '299')";
```

**Note:** Although as suggested by *@Lukasz*, you should really avoid using wildcard **(*)**, and provide an explicit list of columns in the `SELECT` clause.